# Solspace TAG - How to get an URL to tagged entry

Tags: solspace, url, entries, url-title, solspace-tag

I'm running EE 2.7.3 and Tag 4.2.5, and I have tagged entries (products in my case). My stack is how to get URL to “product details” page of tagged product?

For an example I will tag Product#1 from category#1 and subcategory#1, then I will tag Product#2 from category#1 and subcategory#2 and next Product#3 from category#2 and sunbcategory#3. As return URL I suspect to get something like:

```
 Product#1: http://www.domain.com/category#1/subcategory#1/product#1
 Product#2: http://www.domain.com/category#1/subcategory#2/product#2
 Product#3: http://www.domain.com/category#2/subcategory#3/product#3
```

I have currently one channel for products and appropriate template groups for each category/subcategory.

Any clue how to get URLs to work? Should I use in that case Low Seg2Cat or GWcode Categories to get proper URLs based on {url_title} of tagged product?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my problem resolved by using GWCode Categories add-on.

Final code:

```
{exp:tag:entries channel="products" tag="{segment_2}" status="open" dynamic="no"}
  <a href="{site_url}{exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" last_only="yes" style="linear"}{complete_path}{/exp:gwcode_categories}/{url_title}">
     <h3>{title}</h3>
  </a>
{/exp:tag:entries}
```

where `{segment_2}` is a tag name with which product was tagged.